# How to increase $kk in echo by 1?

Tags: php, rss

i am here not going ahead at this point

```
  <?php
     $count = 0;
                $arrImg = array();
                $arrtitle = array();
                    foreach ($feed->get_items() as $kk=> $item) {
                        $feedDescription = $item->get_content();
                        $feedTitle = $item->get_title();
                        //print_r($feedTitle);
                        $image = returnImage($feedDescription);
                        $image = scrapeImage($image);
                        $image = urldecode($image);
                        $arrimg[$count] = $image;
                        $arrtitle[$count] = $feedTitle;
                       //print_r("rajesh".$kk);
       echo '<img class="slide-img-'.$kk.'"  src="' .$arrimg[$kk]. '"   />';
                        $count++;
                 // echo '<br />';
                }
?>
```

i want to add 1 to $kk in echo .but i tried many ways but didnt get hte soln

please help
thanks

Comment: Is `$kk` initialised elsewhere? If not, you will generate `E_NOTICE` errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php
     $count = 0;
     $arrImg = array();
     $arrtitle = array();
     foreach ($feed->get_items() as $kk=> $item) {
         $feedDescription = $item->get_content();
         $feedTitle = $item->get_title();
         //print_r($feedTitle);
         $image = returnImage($feedDescription);
         $image = scrapeImage($image);
         $image = urldecode($image);
         $arrimg[$count] = $image;
         $arrtitle[$count] = $feedTitle;
         //print_r("rajesh".$kk);
         echo '<img class="slide-img-'.($kk+1).'"  src="' .$arrimg[$kk]. '"   />';
         $count++;
         // echo '<br />';
     }
?>
```

Comment: Also have a look at the answer again, which is revised, and which you may prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use pre-increment operator.

```
echo ++$kk;
```

But note this will increment `$kk` itself.

To add one to echo, just do `($kk + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

At what point do you want to increment the variable? You can use the incrementation operator `++` as either a prefix or suffix depending on the timing.

Here's some examples

```
$kk = 1; echo ++$kk, ' ', $kk;
// 2 2

$kk = 1; echo $kk++, ' ', $kk;
// 1 2

$kk = 1; echo $kk, ' ', $kk++, ' ', $kk;
// 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand, why don't you just do directly $bkk+1?

Also are you sure you want to set the image to $arrimg[$count] then call $arrimg[$kk].

I think you should use either $count or $kk for both.